# Custom arrows and boxes in the Beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, boxes, arrows

I have the following Beamer slide:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Potenciação}
   \begin{block}{Propriedades de Potenciação}
      \begin{align}
         a^n &= a . a . a \ldots a \rightarrow n \enspace fatores\\
         a^n &\rightarrow a \enspace (\textbf{base}) \enspace e \enspace n \enspace (\textbf{expoente})
      \end{align}
   \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Is it possible to customize my box and the arrows on my Beamer slide similar to this figure?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced, nobeforeafter,
        colback=cyan!5!white,
        colframe=cyan,
        width=\linewidth, 
        halign=center}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[fragile]
\frametitle{Potenciação}

\begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow=cyan!50]
    $\begin{aligned}
       a^n= \underbrace{a{\cdot}a{\cdot}a \dotsm a}_{n \text{ fatores}}
            &\qquad\qquad&
       \tikzmarknode{A}{a}^{n\leftarrow\text{ expoente}}
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->, shorten <=2pt] (A.south) |- ++ (2em,-1em)
            node[right, font=\footnotesize] {base};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For above image of frame you need to compile NWE at least twice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would better match your expectations :

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red!10,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red!10}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Potenciação}
   \begin{block}{Propriedades de Potenciação}
      \begin{flalign*}
        &\bullet\quad a^n= \underbrace{a . a . a \ldots a}_{ n \enspace fatores}&
        &\bullet\quad(\textbf{base})\leftarrow a^{n\leftarrow(\textbf{expoente})} 
      \end{flalign*}
   \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By using `TikZ` one could reproduce exaclty the example you showed but maybe you wanna stick to the beamer class and only adjust beamer settings.